# How to download a file using wget.download() in python and authenticating with username and password

Tags: python, wget

Unable to download a file from a url using wget in python since the website requires a username and password

I've already tried:

```
import wget

path = /path

url = "https://username:password@website.com"

wget.download(url, path)
```

If I don't include the username and password and simply the url, I end up with an "HTTP:401 Error Unauthorized". If I follow the code above inputting my username and password I get an "Invalid Url"

Comment: Is the URL you're reaching out to definitely determining authorization using HTTP Basic Authentication?

Comment: Could you solve the issue? I have the same currently. Curious to know.